# XPATH select all descendant text nodes in the order they appear excluding some of them

Tags: php, html, xpath

I want to select all descendant text nodes with XPATH in the order they appear in a certain div. Problem being there are nodes I do not want to select.

```
<div class="div-needed">
  <p> Some random text 1<strong>important text 1</strong> more text </p>
  <p> Some random text 2<strong>important text 2</strong> more text </p>
  <p> Some random text 3<strong>important text 3</strong> more text </p>
  <div class="not-select">Unwanted content</div>
  <ul class="unwanted"></ul>
  <p> Some random text 4<strong>important text 4</strong> more text </p>
  <h3>Text I also need</h3>
  <script>
    */Unwanted Code /* 
  </script>
</div>
```

I need `<h3>`, the `<p>` and their children `<strong>` which are descendants from `<div class="div-needed">`, but I also need to obtain them in the order they appear in the HTML; I have tried `div[@class="div-needed"]/descendant::text()[not(@class="not-select")]` trying to select all text nodes and excluding the one I do not want but it does not change the final output. Does anyone know how to exclude some nodes when selecting descendants in XPATH but at the same time keeping nodes the way they appear?

Comment: So what kind of result do you want, why does `div[@class = 'div-needed']/p` not suffice, if you want the `p` elements? It is not clear why you want text nodes, given that you have mixed contents.

Comment: Sometimes it will not only be ```<p>``` what I need. At some point maybe the ```<ul>``` will be something I need.

Comment: Still not clear at which point XPath fails. Of course, in theory, XPath 1.0 returns a node-set which has no order but most XPath APIs return nodes in document order. If a `p` element is your aim, I would select `div[@class = 'div-needed']/p`, if you need the `h3` elements as well, then the union `div[@class = 'div-needed']/p | div[@class = 'div-needed']/h3`.

Comment: Your predicate `descendant::text()[not(@class="not-select")]` is useless because text nodes do not have attributes. Perhaps you want `descendant::*[not(@class="not-select")]/text()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't look for text nodes, if you want the `h3` and the `p` children select e.g. `div[@class = 'div-needed']/p | div[@class = 'div-needed']/h3` or `div[@class = 'div-needed']/*[self::p|self::h3]`. As the `strong` elements are children of the `p` elements the text value of the `p` element contains the complete text; you can either read out `string()` with a relative XPath for each selected `p` or in the DOM the `textContent` property of each `p` or `h3` element (or in general, the selected elements).